# Unable to retrieve connection (Kibana to Elasticsearch)

Tags: ssl, https, elasticsearch, tls, kibana

После настройки ssl и tls elasticsearch работает, браузер распознает сертификат как доверенный, локальный доступ и внешний есть но kibana и metricbeat почему-то не находят его. Ссылка по которой еластик доступен локально из браузера https://10.0.1.103:9200.

**kibana.yml:**

```
server.port: 5601
server.host: "10.0.1.103"
elasticsearch.hosts: ["https://10.0.1.103:9200"]

elasticsearch.username: "lalala"
elasticsearch.password: "lalala"

xpack.security.enabled: true
server.ssl.enabled: true
server.ssl.keystore.path: /home/pms/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-7.6.1/config/cert.p12
server.ssl.keystore.password: ""
elasticsearch.ssl.keystore.path: /home/pms/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-7.6.1/config/cert.p12
elasticsearch.ssl.keystore.password: ""
elasticsearch.ssl.truststore.path: /home/pms/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-7.6.1/config/cert.p12
elasticsearch.ssl.truststore.password: ""
elasticsearch.ssl.verificationMode: certificate
```

**kibana logs:**

```
log   [14:15:36.745] [error][data][elasticsearch] Request error, retrying
GET https://10.0.1.103:9200/_xpack => socket hang up
  log   [14:15:36.748] [error][data][elasticsearch] Request error, retrying
HEAD https://10.0.1.103:9200/.apm-agent-configuration => socket hang up
  log   [14:15:36.750] [error][admin][elasticsearch] Request error, retrying
GET https://10.0.1.103:9200/_nodes?filter_path=nodes.*.version%2Cnodes.*.http.publish_address%2Cnodes.*.ip => socket hang up
  log   [14:15:36.760] [warning][data][elasticsearch] Unable to revive connection: https://10.0.1.103:9200/
  log   [14:15:36.761] [warning][data][elasticsearch] No living connections
  log   [14:15:36.762] [warning][licensing][plugins] License information could not be obtained from Elasticsearch due to Error: No Living connections error
  log   [14:15:36.766] [warning][admin][elasticsearch] Unable to revive connection: https://10.0.1.103:9200/
  log   [14:15:36.767] [warning][admin][elasticsearch] No living connections
```

**elasticsearch.yml:**

```
network.host: 10.0.1.103
http.port: 9200
xpack.security.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode: certificate 
xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.path: cert.p12 
xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.secure_password: ""
xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.path: cert.p12 
xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.secure_password: ""
xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.http.ssl.keystore.path: cert.p12
xpack.security.http.ssl.keystore.secure_password: ""
xpack.security.http.ssl.truststore.path: cert.p12
```

**elasticsearch logs:**

```
[2020-05-13T10:09:55,027][INFO ][o.e.h.AbstractHttpServerTransport] [pms-new] publish_address {10.0.1.103:9200}, bound_addresses {10.0.1.103:9200}
[2020-05-13T10:09:55,028][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [pms-new] started
[2020-05-13T10:15:39,220][WARN ][o.e.x.s.t.n.SecurityNetty4HttpServerTransport] [pms-new] received plaintext http traffic on an https channel, closing connection Netty4HttpChannel{localAddress=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:9200, remoteAddress=/10.0.1.103:36444}
```

Comment: Оттуда, где хостятся kibana и metricbeat хост 10.0.1.103 доступен? Возможно, нужна статическая маршрутизация, которая добавляется через командную строку командой route add ...?

Comment: @hwak, es и kibana запускаются на одном и том же хосту 10.0.1.103.

Comment: использовать localhost или 127.0.0.1 в качестве адреса es пробовали?

Comment: @hwak да, не помогло. Я решил проблему. Сертификат который использует es был сгенерирован certbot'ом, я сгенерил для kibana сертификат используя ./bin/elasticsearch-certutil ca. Дело в сертификате.